# Dependency Issue with Android project

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an Android Project for my IoT class.  I have followed youtube video from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7CGcFjQQtQ&t=4538s.. My github repo is at https://github.com/twobit-five/SphereLink/tree/Code_CleanUp.  I have a few branches, but in the current branch I was attempting to clean up some of the code and add the UI functionality to the project.  This has been a huge learning curve for me. However, I am stuck at the current build issue.  The branch was committed with erros, which seem to be just compounding as I attempt to solve them.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

I am looking for tips where I might have gone wrong and to be able to successfully build the project as is.

Edit:
There were numerous build errors.

This version (1.1.0) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.0 which is not known to be compatible.

There were also build errors which stated something about JVM7 and JVM8 and duplicate classes at one point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't push to your git. Please down load patch from https://files.fm/u/gqq45399f and apply it in your branch (Code_CleanUp)

1. With compose I use compose-bom (setup: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#bom-version-mapping )
2. Change kotlin plugin version map with compose( you can see detail in here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin ), because you use compose 1.4.4 so you need update kotlint to 1.8.10
3. Update version of dagger
4. implementation androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1 to fix error : MediaSessionCompat:Targeting S+ (version 31 and above)...

Your app after I change
[image]

Comment: Could you expand your answer and include what the problem was as well as what you did to solve it? The file you shared might not be accessible in the future which leads to an unusable answer

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue. I spent several hours without making any progress and not knowing how to proceed.